# fstream fails at inputting negative numbers

Tags: c++

so I was trying to do a little program, and when I try to input negative numbers from a .txt file, my program fails and just outputs random things after the first negative number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

struct imones{
    string vardas;
    int koordx;
    int koordy;
};

void skaityti(int &n, int &m, imones A[]){
    ifstream ivest;
    ivest.open("U1.txt");
    ivest >> n >> m;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        ivest >> A[i].vardas >> A[i].koordx >> A[i].koordy;
    }
    ivest.close();
}


int main()
{
    imones A[50];
    int n, m;
    skaityti(n, m, A);
    cout << A[0].vardas << " " << A[0].koordx << " " << A[0].koordy<<endl;
    cout << A[1].vardas << " " << A[1].koordx << " " << A[1].koordy<<endl;
    cout << A[2].vardas << " " << A[2].koordx << " " << A[2].koordy<<endl;
    cout << A[3].vardas << " " << A[3].koordx << " " << A[3].koordy<<endl;
    cout << A[4].vardas << " " << A[4].koordx << " " << A[4].koordy<<endl;
}
```

U1.txt:

```
5 30
Siuntuva    2 3
Auda        3 –1
Kostisa     –3 –2
Linga       3 0
Austuva     –2 –4
```

And when outputting, the -1 and everything after it becomes random numbers.

Comment: You should check if the reading worked. Something like `if (!(ivest >> n >> m)) throw std::runtime_error("Failed reading ints");`. Also once you have a read error the `fstream` stays in an error state refusing to read anything anymore until you clear it.

Comment: That isn't a regular hyphen; your posted text `'–'` uses octet value is 226. Try using a *proper* `'-'` instead, i.e. ascii code 45. Using proper data ([fixed here](http://pastebin.com/97ssUntw)) produces what you seek.

Comment: A big thank you to both of you! WhozCraig, especially you - I was out of hope when I tried to fix that for 2 hours!

Answer (score 2):

In your input file lines, those `-` characters seem just a *little* too wide, though it is *very* subtle and hard to spot:

```
- : a regular minus sign.
– : one from your file.
```

That's why your inputs are not working, because your input data doesn't match the required format. This is causing the `operator>>` to fail and therefore not loading any useful values into the array.

While it wouldn't have indicated *why* it failed, you would have at least been notified of the problem had you checked the `operator>>` result with something like:

```
if (! (ivest >> A[i].vardas >> A[i].koordx >> A[i].koordy))
    throw std::runtime_error("Something went wrong reading the file");
```

Other than "Mickey Mouse" programs (or "Janet and John", or "See Spot Run", or any other phrases indicating extreme simplicity), you should generally prefer checking statements that *can* fail, to see if they *did* fail. Even throwing an exception and exiting the program is better than continuing with bad data.

As it turns out, the character you are using looks to be something like an `en-dash`, Unicode `U+8211`, whereas what you need is a `hyphen-minus`, `U+0045`. You'll often these (and `em-dashes`, and “smart quotes”, which also cause trouble) when you've copy-and-pasted stuff out of a word-processing document into your data files or source code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Completely missed out on the wide hyphens :p